# Program to calculate sum of list of numbers

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I tried to run this one but I don't know where the error is.

```
include "emu8086.inc"
ORG 100
.data
ARRAY DB 12H, 24H, 26H, 63H, 25H, 86H, 2FH, 33H, 10H, 35H
SUM DW 0
.code
START: MOV AX, @DATA
MOV DS, AX
MOV CL, 10
XOR DI, DI
MOV BX, OFFSET ARRAY
BACK: MOV AL, [BX+DI]
MOV AH, 00H
MOV SUM, AX
INC DI
DEC CL
JNZ BACK

                   ; print out the number in ax
CALL print_num      ; using procedure
RET
END
```

Answer (score 0):

> `ORG 100`

If you're going to create a .COM program then the correct value for this `ORG` directive is 256, or 100h when expressed in hexadecimal. You forgot the **h** suffix!

Also the .COM program format is simple enough that you don't need any of the following: `.data`, `.code`, `MOV AX, @DATA`, and `MOV DS, AX`. You should however **place the code before the data** as I did in below program.

> `MOV SUM, AX`

The task is to get the "sum". You need to use the `add` instruction on this line.

> `CALL print_num`

Before you can use the *print_num* procedure from *emu8086.inc*, you need to declare it using `DEFINE_PRINT_NUM` and `DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS`.

```
include 'emu8086.inc'
ORG 100h

; code
MOV CL, 10
XOR DI, DI
MOV BX, OFFSET ARRAY
BACK: MOV AL, [BX+DI]
MOV AH, 0
ADD SUM, AX
INC DI
DEC CL
JNZ BACK

CALL print_num
RET               ; End of the .COM program

; data
ARRAY DB 12h, 24h, 26h, 63h, 25h, 86h, 2Fh, 33h, 10h, 35h
SUM   DW 0

DEFINE_PRINT_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS
END
```